# Convert CoapExchange to Byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, scala, byte, type-conversion

I new in scala language.

I hame a method what takes on input CoapExchange object:
`def handlePOST (request: CoapExchange) {
.....`
How to convert `org.eclipse.californium.core.server.resources.CoapExchange` object to `Byte[]` in scala
Thanks!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237666/how-do-i-convert-a-java-byte-array-into-a-scala-byte-array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8302493/203968

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, let's look at [the source](https://github.com/eclipse/californium/blob/master/californium-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/californium/core/server/resources/CoapExchange.java)

And we find

```
/**
 * Gets the request payload as byte array.
 *
 * @return the request payload
 */
public byte[] getRequestPayload() {
    return exchange.getRequest().getPayload();
}
```

or you can use [the documentation here](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/ch.ethz.inf.vs/californium/0.18.7-final/ch/ethz/inf/vs/californium/server/resources/CoapExchange.html#getRequestPayload--)

Comment: thx for your  answer, but me need all request(body and headers) not a Payload

Comment: What do you mean by "all request"?  All the bytes "on the wire", including message id etc? And why would you use Californium and still want that?

Comment: "-What do you mean by "all request"?":
need all data what I getting from input(headers, message bode, port,url.....)
"And why would you use Californium and still want that? – The Archetypal Paul just now":
Total project requirement

Comment: OK, then I don't understand the requirement. It's like using (say) httpcommons and expecting to be able to get the entire stream of bytes sent back and forth on the TCP connection. The library probably just doesn't track that sort of thing.